# Task Scheduler Run Whether User Logged Or Not Issue

Tags: powershell, task, scheduler

I'm running a powershell script with task scheduler and it runs fine when the option 'run when the user is logged on' is selected.

This isn't efficient for obvious reasons. Is there a specific reason as to why when I choose 'run whether user is logged on or not' that the script doesn't run?

I've tried with local admin as well and my account. I have full administrator rights so I don't see it as a permissions issue. Any clues?

Thank you so much

This is the task scheduler export xml.

FYI, the script opens an excel, refreshes all connections, and saves.
(The file is in the one drive) Regardless of it being in the one drive or not, it doesn't refresh a file on my desktop.

I have even tried passing the UNC path in the script as opposed to C:/users/--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2015-05-28T09:34:25.8180083</Date>
    <Author>-----</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT1H</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2015-05-29T08:20:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>------</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>powershell</Command>
      <Arguments>-File "scriptpathhere"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: @arco444, I read something about that. Will look into it more in depth. Thank you for your input

Comment: @arco444 No. At work I have a scheduled task that collects log records and puts them in Excel sheets (for nicer formatting/filtering). Works just fine.

Comment: Does the script actually not run at all? Add logging to your script to make sure of that. Also, what does the eventlog and the task history say about it?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the task runs perfectly fine when run when this user is logged on is selected. The eventlog and task history say that it successfully completed. Thank you for your help. Also, I'm grabbing the excel from my one drive. In order to assure that this wasn't the issue, I tried running the task to refresh a local item while the 'run whether user is logged on or not' and that still didn't work. I appreciate your help man